# Unable to locate package php8.0, bug in installing php8 in ubuntu

Tags: php, ppa

I've Ubuntu 16.04, and I ran the below command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

The final result looks like this:

```
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp94jbo60i/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp94jbo60i/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp94jbo60i/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

then I run this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The result of this command is:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

and then I run this code to install php8.0:

```
sudo apt install php8.0-fpm libapache2-mod-fcgid
```

It always returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-fpm
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-fpm'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.0-fpm'
```

I highly appreciate it if anyone knows and shares the solution.

Comment: 16.04 is beyond Standard Support and is offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu, per the Help Center (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 3):

Since php 5.something fpm is part of the core php, not a separate package. So if you have installed php8.0 then you should just need to enable it (probably `sudo a2enconf php8.0-fpm` but I am only guessing here).

If you look at the package details for the repository you added you can see what is in the php8.0 package:
[https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=php8.0&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=php8.0&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=)